# show alert if input type file is not image ,using jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with input type file, if image selected it will show preview if other than image selected (pdf/docx)I want to show alert invalid,but getting error :Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<input type='file' id='input1'>
<div class="hide_this" style="display:none;">    <img id='imagepreview1' width="100" height="100" >
<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" style="position: absolute;top:30px;opacity:1.2;">
  <span aria-hidden="true" style="color:black;">&times;</span>
</button>
</div>


<script>
$("#input1").change(function() {
    readURL(this);
    $('#imagepreview1').show();
    $('.hide_this').css({
        'display': 'block'
    });
});
$('.close').click(function() {
    $(".hide_this").hide();
    document.getElementById("input1").value = "";
    $("#imagepreview1").hide();
});

function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var ext = input.files[0].split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
            if ($.inArray(ext, ['gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']) == -1) {
                alert('invalid extension!');
            }
            $('#imagepreview1').prop('src', e.target.result).show();
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: where is your `my_file_field` input defined ?

Comment: Use `([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp))$)` that regex to check for a valid image extension. Because I could beat your check by just making a file named jpg.exe

Comment: Might also consider using an `accept` attribute https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful

Comment: that would imply `input.files[0]` is undefined, which clearly it can't be!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to my comment and your request, besides the undefined error. You could beat your security check by just making a file named: **jpg.exe.**

Use a regex expression, and make sure your file is actually selected. Use the `onselect` event.

```js
let good = 'test.jpg';
let bad = 'jpg.test';
let re = (/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(good);
if (re) {
    console.log('Good', good);
}

console.log('Bad:', bad);
```

And make sure change to this

```
let ext = $("#input1").val().split(".").pop().toLowerCase();
```

For a PDF, you could use a library after evaluating the expression.

```js
var url = 'https://s1.q4cdn.com/806093406/files/doc_downloads/test.pdf';


let re = (/\.(pdf)$/i).test(url);
if (re) {
  console.log(re);
  //
  // Asynchronous download PDF
  //
  var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(url);
  loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
    //
    // Fetch the first page
    //
    pdf.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
      var scale = 1.5;
      var viewport = page.getViewport({
        scale: scale,
      });
      //
      // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
      //
      var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      canvas.height = viewport.height;
      canvas.width = viewport.width;
      //
      // Render PDF page into canvas context
      //
      var renderContext = {
        canvasContext: context,
        viewport: viewport,
      };
      page.render(renderContext);
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.2.2/pdf.js"></script>
<canvas id="the-canvas" style="border:1px  solid black"></canvas>
```

Comment: I messed the expression up, I am going to fix it. My bad, one sec I'll help. But that's the idea.

Comment: thanks for your help,last thing just now i got requirement  if pdf/docx type file then use embed tag to show preview ,instead of showing alert  currently I am developing project so I got requirement like this

Comment: Ok, give me a sec. I won't abandon you.

Comment: @Anonymous I gave you an example for a pdf, just use https://regexr.com/ to test your regex expression. And for Javascript regex, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: thank you so much for your help and valuable time to solve this issue

Comment: @Anonymous I updated the PDF example, there was a good library to load a PDF. It uses the check for the PDF url, then loads it if it is a valid filename.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to read the value of an input with an ID of `my_file_field` which doesn't exist - use `input1` instead:

```
var ext = $("#input1").val().split(".").pop().toLowerCase();
```

Comment: I want to show preview if file type is pdf or docx in html embed tag, how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You file input is `#input1` not `#my_file_field`

change

```
var ext = $('#my_file_field').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
```

to

```
var ext = $('#input1').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
```